# Commas Between the Subject and the Verb and Predicate - A Mistake or Acceptable Usage?

Tags: word-usage, commas

I have always believed that the placement of a comma between the subject and the verb and predicate was an error (as in "Whoever is capable of forgetting a benefit, is an enemy to society."). However, recently I have come across such usage in edited academic prose - incidentally all in legal scholarship. To give a few examples:

> "One approach would potentially have any military operation between
>   the state forces and active members of group X, seen as part of the
>   armed conflict." (Noam Lubell & Nathan Derejko, “A Global Battlefield?
>   Drones and the Geographical Scope of Armed Conflict”, *Journal of
>   International Criminal Justice*, vol. 11, no. 1 (2013), p. 82).

and

> "The status of the individuals targeted or the attributes of the
>   objects targeted, will then be relevant as to the lawfulness in
>   accordance with IHL (as opposed to its applicability)." (*Ibid.*, p.
>   83).

and

> "Thus, if a non-state armed group that is based in state A, commits
>   hostilities that amount to an armed conflict on the territory of the
>   High Contracting Party B, the protocol requirements are satisfied." (Sandesh Sivakumaran, *The
>   Law of Non-International Armed Conflict*, Oxford University Press,
>   2012, p. 231).

The commas before "seen", "will", and "commits" strike me as classical mistakes. Am I missing something here? Do these commas serve a function that I'm unaware of? Is this perhaps part of academic usage? I am yet to find any style guide that endorses this type of comma.

Comment: Related, and probably a duplicate: [Is a comma necessary in "What's funny, is..."?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76850/is-a-comma-necessary-in-what-s-funny-is)

Comment: Also related: [Comma between subject and predicate](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/353110/comma-between-subject-and-predicate-when-predicate-is-noun-clause-ending-in-ver)

Comment: You were probably taught that that was an inviolable rule; however the more we get exposed to how English is actually used the more we are such rules lack scope, don't always apply, are arbitrary, etc.  Additionally, legalese goes by different rules than other types of writing.

Comment: You are right. In Present-day English there is normally a strong prohibition on punctuation separating subject and verb. Your examples certainly violate that prohibition and thus would normally be wrong. Why they were written that way? Who knows?

Comment: Those commas aren't needed, even if some are helpful. *One approach…* prolly uses *X, …* to avoid seeing *Group X* rather than the *operation* as part of the conflict… which the full stop obviated. Why trust anyone who wrote *… have (anything) seen…* instead of *see (anything) as…*?

*The status…* seems to contort itself for the sake of it. My doubts are doubled in any legal context; I believe lawyers today try to abjure commas, to avoid ambiguity.

The *non-state* conflict prolly needs neither *state A,* nor *Party B,* even if it needs *Thus,*.