# The grammar structure of this sentence which looks like one subject is hidden

Tags: grammar

I am trying to understand the grammar structure of the given sentence below:

**For example, considering the one-loop exchange of W or Z prime gauge bosons, results in theoretical predictions for the muon and electron anomalies having the same sign.**

Here, my question is what is the subject in front of **results in** in the sentence and what is the full grammar structure of the given sentence?

Many thanks for any help in advance

Comment: considering (subject) results (verb).  I guess grammatically,  "considering" is a gerund (= verb "-ing" form used as a noun).

Comment: This doesn't seem to make any sense at all. Is there some more context that might help us? (There has to be ... the sentence starts with "for example".)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is a comma necessary in "What’s funny, is …"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76850/is-a-comma-necessary-in-what-s-funny-is)  See also [commas between the subject and the verb / predicate – a mistake or acceptable?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/418555/commas-between-the-subject-and-the-verb-and-predicate-a-mistake-or-acceptable) .This seems to commit the (near-)cardinal sin of putting a comma between subject and verb.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have failed to give context, there should be no comma between "bosons" and "results"

1. **For example**, Fronting adverbial free modifier
2. **Considering** = a reduced conditional = “if we consider”
3. **the one-loop exchange of W or Z prime gauge bosons,** = subject of noun clause
4. **results in** = phrasal verb of the noun clause
5. **theoretical predictions for the muon and electron anomalies having the same sign.** = Object of **results in**

3 + 4 + 5 = content/ noun clause that is the object of the verb “consider”

Comment: First of all, many thanks for your explanation. What you pointed out is exactly consistent with mine. However, the given sentence is correct and is given by my supervisor. So I am curious whether there is more of English grammar structure which I am not familiar with.

Comment: @Peter Shor You're right - I have amended it.

Comment: @lhcQFT *However, the given sentence is correct* If you believe that you should ask why there is a comma between the subject and verb. I would be interested to hear your supervisor's explanation. The sentence reduces to *For example, considering x, results in predictions*: with a comma, this makes no sense.

Comment: I think you are right. I need to make this clear by discussing with my supervisor.

Answer (score 1):

Badly written English is not easy to sort out. The method is of course to break the sentence into usable parts and go by example from there. The context this sentence finds itself in is more important since inferences from this text without context may not be accurate.

The offending text can be rewritten as;
"For example, A, results in B..."

Where A is "considering the one-loop exchange of W or Z prime gauge bosons" and B is "theoretical predictions"

It is most unfortunate that the A is enclosed in commas making it a parenthetical. Also that A starts with "considering" since this takes the sentence into a different direction while we are waiting for the parenthetical to close.

An improvement would be;
"For example, *since* one-loop exchange of W or Z prime gauge bosons, results in theoretical predictions for the muon and electron anomalies having the same sign."

Depending on the context the *since* might be replaced by *because*.

Another might be;
"For example, the one-loop exchange of W or Z prime gauge bosons, *resulting* in theoretical predictions for the muon and electron anomalies having the same sign."

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I think your last choice sound very reasonable. Actually, this sentence is given by my supervisor who is British, therefore I think the given sentence is correct and there would be something I didn't know.

Comment: **Considering** how difficult the sentence is for the most seasoned to parse **results in questioning** any insistence that "my supervisor ... is British, therefore ... the given sentence is correct."

Comment: It sounds as though your supervisor was speaking rather than writing. It is not at all unusual for people, even English supervisors, to change the nature of the sentence while speaking, getting lost as it were, leaving the listener to parse an mis-formed sentence. The supervisor's authority seems to be the only reason the sentence must be correct.