# Why the comma is used in the sentence by Jane Austen

Tags: punctuation, commas, syntactic-analysis

I cannot understand the usage of comma after "chapel" in this sentence:

> Its long, damp passages, its narrow cells and ruined ***chapel,*** were to be within her daily reach, and she could not entirely subdue the hope of some traditional legends, some awful memorials of an injured and ill-fated nun.

Why is a comma used here, and what is the sentence structure?

The sentence is an excerpt from "Northanger Abbey" by Jane Austen.

Comment: Which comma are you referring to? There are quite a lot in that one sentence.

Comment: I am referring to the comma after the word **chapel**.[ Its long, damp passages, its narrow cells and ruined chapel **,** (the comma right here)]

Comment: Sorry it seems I can't read questions properly

Comment: Jane _Austen_  lists three things (passages, cells and chapel) which were going to be near Catherine while she stayed at the Abbey. The comma at the end of the list isn't strictly necessary, but it makes the sentence easier to understand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is a comma necessary in "What’s funny, is …"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76850/is-a-comma-necessary-in-what-s-funny-is) where " 'The New Oxford Guide' to Writing By Thomas S. Kane {1988} doesn't accept the mantra 'Never separate the subject from its verb with a comma' as being an inviolable edict... " appears. Other punctuation guides maintain that the rule is inviolate. They have to rate this as poor punctuation by Austin.

Comment: See also @John Lawler's comment [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/353110/comma-between-subject-and-predicate-when-predicate-is-noun-clause-ending-in-ver), where he says that there _is_ an intonation contour involved in at least some related cases, but not the pause normally associated with a comma. 'These are attempts to punctuate the intonation contour that separates the complex noun phrase and its predicate.' Perhaps a half-comma is needed, perhaps a comma half the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the relevant portion of the original sentence:

> Its long, damp passages, its narrow cells and ruined chapel, were to be within her daily reach.

I would interpret it in this way:

> Its long, damp passages <sup>(its narrow cells and ruined chapel)</sup> were to be within her daily reach.
>
> → Its long, damp passages  were to be within her daily reach.

In other words, the second and third commas in the original version are used to represent parenthetical information that could be removed without affecting the syntax of the sentence.

---

If it's supposed to be describing three things that *were to be within her daily reach*, then the use of the third comma is somewhat misleading.

Instead, I would rephrase it in a few different ways:

> 1. Its long, damp passages, its narrow cells and ***its*** ruined chapel were to be within her daily reach.

This removes the original third comma and adds *its* in front of the third item in order to preserve parallelism with the syntax of the first two items.

If you wished, you could add a serial comma after *cells*.

> 2. Its long, damp passages, its narrow cells and its ruined chapel: they were to be within her daily reach.
> 3. Its long, damp passages, its narrow cells and its ruined chapel—they were to be within her daily reach.

Both the colon and the dash add the kind of pause after the list of items that a comma normally would—but, unlike the comma, they don't indicate that anything is parenthetical.